# Azure cli or rest api end to upload custom policy

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c, azure-cli, azure-cli2

I am trying to automate the upload of custom policies as I have multiple tenants and each tenant consists of multiple custom policies.
I am interested in either Azure cli or SDK for the same. I searched on Google but could not find anything related.

Anyone work on this kind of automation?

Comment: You can use bicep to deploy custom policies.

Comment: Have you got an example of using Bicep to deploy Azure AD B2C custom policies [Peter Bons](https://stackoverflow.com/users/932728/peter-bons) - I have never seen this be implemented.

Comment: Uploading policies using a API call is the easiest way for me at this point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Local/Manual deployment options:

1. PowerShell Script again the [Trust Framework Policy Graph API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/trustframeworkpolicy?view=graph-rest-beta), [Azure AD PowerShell module](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/manage-custom-policies-powershell#upload-a-new-policy), or using the [Microsoft.Graph.Beta PowerShell SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/microsoftgraph/installation?view=graph-powershell-1.0) - **You would need to handle variable substitution** before uploading the policies.
2. Using VSCode, use the [Azure AD B2C Tools](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=AzureADB2CTools.aadb2c) extension, which allows adding multiple environments. Variable substitution is handled by the package.

CI/CD Pipeline:

1. [Azure DevOps pipeline](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/deploy-custom-policies-devops) - **You would need to handle variable substitution** in the pipeline. [Azure DevOps pipeline for Azure AD B2C Sample](https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/blob/master/policies/devops-pipeline)
2. [GitHub Actions pipeline](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/deploy-custom-policies-github-action) - **You would need to handle variable substitution** in the pipeline. [Github Action for Azure AD B2C using ieftool Sample](https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/blob/master/policies/ieftool-github-actions)
3. [IEF Tool npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ieftool/v/1.0.4) - **You would need to handle variable substitution** in the pipeline. Sample below for Azure DevOps Pipeline

```yaml
- task: NodeTool@0
  displayName: 'Install Node'
  inputs:
    versionSpec: '10.x'

- script: npm install -g ieftool
  displayName: 'Install IEF Tool'

- script: ieftool deploy -t $(TenantId) -c $(DeploymentClientId) -s $(DeploymentClientSecret) -p $(Pipeline.Workspace)/b2c-policies
  displayName: 'Uploading IEF policies'
```

Comment: Thanks @bolt-io. ieftool is very easy to set up. I am able to upload policies. I hope it will overwrite the existing policy if I upload the new version of that policy. second thing, Is it possible to instruct this tool to follow a particular sequence while uploading policies?

Comment: Yes, if the policy is already in your tenant, it will overwrite the policy with the new version, so you do not need to worry about deleting anything. The tool is smart enough to work out the hierarchy and inheritance of your policies and upload accordingly. So the base will be uploaded before extensions and so on.

Comment: Please do not forget to "Accept the answer” and “up-vote” wherever the information provided helps you, this can be beneficial to other community members.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with [Azure Pipelines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/deploy-custom-policies-devops) or you can use the [API's](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/trustframeworkpolicy?view=graph-rest-beta) directly.

Comment: hi rbrayb, I tried the api . however got this error.
b'{"error":{"code":"BadRequest","message":"Resource not found for the segment \'<TrustFrameworkPolicy        xmlns:xsi=\\"http:\'.","innerError":{"date":"2024-01-24T10:28:02","request-id":"23200959-2559-4138-9719-c
ac44f4cc068","client-request-id":"23200959-2559-4138-9719-cac44f4cc068"}}}'
policy content is correct and policy exist.

Comment: I have fixed the above error. xml file should be in bytes(encoded="utf-8").